# How to select object Appended from another .blend file?

Tags: modeling

So, I imported the Object folder from another .blend file. using Append button. I see the model here and everything, with its rigs (I guess that's the correct word) and etc. The problem is, I can't really select it, if I do it with B, it selects other characters too (They are placed close to each other). Is there any way to select that character only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to append from a blend file next time, try to append it in a New Layer for total selection control.

Even if you are importing a model, import them in a new layer

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to see the model in the outliner and highlight it (thus selecting it) there. You might have to click on some plus signs to open it out and find the model you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to group your objects and rig in the source blend, and then append the group instead of objects. So you can press `Shift+G` > `Group` to select all object in this group.